# How to rotate shape with transform

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a rectangle which I am rotating it to -45 but on drag the rotation is not applied.

Code:

```
function createPoly(x, y)
{
    var width = 41;
    var height = 41;
    var centreX = width / 2;
    var centreY = height / 2;
    var shape = d3.select(this);
    var poly = svg.append("g")
            .classed("bpmnGateway", true)
            .append('svg:rect')
            .attr("type", "poly")
            .attr("x", (x - centreX))
            .attr("y", (y - centreY))
            .attr("width", 41)
            .attr("height", 41)
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)")
            .attr("stroke-width", "1.5px")
            .attr("stroke", "#7E7E7E")
            .style('cursor', 'move')
            .style("fill", "#FFED6B")
            .call(drag);
}

function drag()
{
    if (shape.attr('type') === 'poly')
    {
        translate = d3.transform(shape.attr("transform")).translate;
        var x = d3.event.dx + translate[0];
        var y = d3.event.dy + translate[1];
        shape.attr("transform", "rotate(-45)")
        shape.attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
    }
}
```

I tried with rotate option inside drag function which didn't work. How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second attr function overwrites the first. You could just do both in one e.g.

```
   shape.attr("transform", "rotate(-45) translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
```

or

```
   shape.attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ") rotate(-45)");
```

Depending on the order you want the transforms to be applied.

Comment: Thank you. On drag drop the shape is getting displaced. I guess its with translate. How do I fix it?

Comment: Ask another question and provide something runnable e.g. a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Tried with stackoverflow snippet and also fiddle but unable to get it running because functions are being called before dom is loaded. Here's is the new question posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989045/how-to-apply-proper-coordinates-for-rotated-shape-on-drag-drop

Comment: Finally created a new question with snippet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002902/drop-drop-rotated-shape-based-on-mouse-position Please have a look